# Azure edit a required claim for service principal

Tags: azure, powershell

how can i edit in azure for my enterprise application (service principal) the required claim with PowerShell? Tried code from the official docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping

if i execute the code Get-AzureADPolicy this error appears. Of course i installed the Module AzureADPreview and connected to AzureAD.

```
Get-AzureADPolicy : The term 'Get-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADPolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureADPolicy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The claim i want to edit via PowerShell:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   You can surely connect to Azure AD and execute the required powershell commands for updating the claims for a service principal as shown in the screenshot below: -

[image: Powershell execution]

But as per your explanation, you were not able to get any output for **‘Get-AzureADPolicy’**. Thus, for that purpose, please execute the commands below in consecutive manner: -

```
  ‘Disconnect-AzureAD’
  ‘Install-Module AzureADPreview -AllowClobber’
  ‘Install-Module AzureAD -AllowClobber’
```

Then restart the powershell and connect to Azure AD once again and then execute the **‘Get-AzureADPolicy’**, you should be able to get the required output.